# Is it okay to use down-votes to attack another person?

Tags: support, voting, abuse

I would like to assume the answer is no, but it bears asking.

I just discovered that someone has systematically gone through every question I've asked on drupal.stackexchange.com, and every answer I've given (or very nearly every one) and down-voted them.  In the course of 12 minutes yesterday there are 34 down-votes in a row: clearly this is either a bug in the system (very unlikely), or an attack.

Is this okay to do?  Can moderators do anything about such abuses?

Comment: As an aside, the attacker's plan backfired.  5 up-votes so far for asking this question.  Haha.

Comment: lol ! looks like your attacker hasnt left you yet ! I see a -1 for this question too :D

Comment: @2-Stroker It could be it is another user who down-voted this question because s/he didn't like it for any reason. (I did up-vote it.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No it's absolutely not ok, but it does happen.

Either the questions/answers you've written have suddenly got a lot of attention and were received very badly by a large volume of users (highly unlikely, they're of good quality), or an individual is singling you out for whatever reason.

In cases as blatant as this the system will automatically reverse those downvotes at some point in the next 24 hours so there's no need to worry about it.

If for whatever reason that reversal doesn't happen, or you continue to get what you feel are unreasonable downvotes that the system isn't automatically reversing, let a moderator know via a flag and we'll see what can be done.

See also: [What is serial voting and how does it affect me?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me)

Comment: This might be useful too: [This account is temporarily suspended for voting irregularities.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98467/this-account-is-temporarily-suspended-for-voting-irregularities)

Comment: Thanks! I really appreciate your attention to this situation.  (Makes me glad I voted you in as moderator ;)

Answer (score 3):

Your reputation change has been -68 because of down-votes you got in few minutes. You also got 10 down-votes in a minute, which means the user didn't even read your posts, but simply down-voted them. That is what I call voting irregularities.

I am sure the script for voting irregularities will catch this, and revert the down-votes. I will keep an eye on this.

As side note, when a question is closed as off-topic, or not constructive, the system automatically down-votes the question. If you see a single down-vote in a question that has been closed for those reasons, that is not a user who down-voted you.

Comment: Will the user who did this have disciplinary action taken?

Comment: Voting irregularities are a reason for suspension. The system has still to catch the irregularities; it can take up to 24 hours.

Comment: @kiamlaluno So the script will only reverse down votes and not penalize the down voter ? It should penalize the down voter as well right ?

Comment: @2-Stroker The system doesn't automatically penalise the serial downvoter, the 'SE way' is to deal with it silently, at least from an automated standpoint. Moderators can take further action though, if the specific situation warrants it. Rest assured if there's anything to handle, it will be handled :)

Comment: The down-votes were reversed. Thanks for your help!